# Google calendar api acl

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, acl

I was trying to use API to make some changes on my google calendar.

I have created a project on google cloud console, enable calendar API, and got the credential ready. The OAuth scope I set is:

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secret.json", scopes=scopes)
```

And I got both credentials for my account.

```
credentials = flow.run_console()
```

I wanted to use ACL to gain access to the calendar, so I tried "get" and "insert" these two functions. Codes are as follows:

```
rule = service.acl().get(calendarId='primary', ruleId='ruleId').execute()

print('%s: %s' % (rule['id'], rule['role']))
```

```
rule = {
    'scope': {
        'type': 'group',
        'value': 'default',
    },
    'role': 'owner'
}

created_rule = service.acl().insert(calendarId='primary', body=rule).execute()

print(created_rule)
```

However, the results show that I have some problems with the access part.

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/acl/ruleId?alt=json
returned "Invalid resource id value.">
```

and

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/acl?alt=json
returned "Invalid scope value.">
```

what step have I miss or do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- The first error shows up in [Acl.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/get) whenever you specify an invalid `ruleId`. So make sure you are providing a valid `ruleId` in here:

```py
rule = service.acl().get(calendarId='primary', ruleId='valid-rule-id').execute()
```

If you don't know the `ruleId`, you can look for it by calling [Acl.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list).

- About the second error, the problem is that you are providing a wrong request body for [Acl.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert). If you want to share this calendar with a `group`, you should provide a valid email address of the group in `scope.value`. `default` is not a valid value. Your request body should be something like this:

```py
rule = {
    'scope': {
        'type': 'group',
        'value': 'group-email-address',
    },
    'role': 'owner'
}
```

You will find the group email address if you click `About` in the corresponding group.

I hope this is of any help.